# Need to pass values for nsg rules in terraform resource block from a map type variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying a create a resource block for **azurerm_network_security_rule** such that it can be mapped with subnet variable being used in resource block as well so that subnet association with nsg would be easy.

for eg. variable is like

```
variable "subnets" {
  description = "A list of subnets inside the VPC"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    subnet = {
      name           = "test"
      address_prefix = ["x.x.x.x/x"]
      attached_nat   = "false"
      inbound_rules = [
        # [name, priority, direction, access, protocol, destination_port_range, source_address_prefix, destination_address_prefix]
        ["http", "100", "Inbound", "Allow", "Tcp", "80", "*", "0.0.0.0/0"],
      ]
      outbound_rules = [
        # [name, priority, direction, access, protocol, destination_port_range, source_address_prefix, destination_address_prefix]
        ["ntp_out", "103", "Outbound", "Allow", "Udp", "123", "", "0.0.0.0/0"],
      ]
    }
 }
}
```

Getting error

```
**Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on main.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "subnet":
│  120:    for_each = concat([for k, v in var.subnets: {"inbound_rules"=lookup(v,"inbound_rules",[])}], [for k, v in var.subnets: {"outbound_rules"=lookup(v,"outbound_rules",[])}])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.subnets is map of object with 1 element
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type │ tuple.╵**
```

my resource block is like -

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                = format("%s-${each.value.name}")
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name  
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "subnet" {
   for_each = concat([for k, v in var.subnets: {"inbound_rules"=lookup(v,"inbound_rules",[])}], [for k, v in var.subnets: {"outbound_rules"=lookup(v,"outbound_rules",[])}])
  name                       = each.value[0]
  priority                   = each.value[1]
  direction                  = each.value[2] 
  access                     = each.value[3] 
  protocol                   = each.value[4] 
  source_port_range          = "*"
  destination_port_range     = each.value[5] 
  source_address_prefix      = each.value[6]
  destination_address_prefix = each.value[7] 
  description                = "${each.value[2]}_Port_${each.value[5]}"
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.subnet[each.key].name
}
```

If someone can help figuring out the loop to put in for_each to achieve it.

Comment: Why not convert the `inbound_rules` and `outbound_rules` to key/value pairs as well, i.e. `name = "http", priority = "100"` etc. instead of using a list?

Comment: yeah that could be done but I was thinking to keep variables to single line otherwise subnet variable is already big it might become huge

Comment: Let me try to create an example. I'm guessing you want to use the same resource block for both inbound and outbound rules?

Comment: correct yeah that's why concat both inbound and outbound rule

Comment: How many security groups are there? Would you need mapping between security groups and rules as well?

Comment: Also, would you mind adding `azurerm_network_security_group` block of code to the question?

Comment: each subnet will have 1 sg and sg rule would be mapped with network_security_group_name parameter for each sg created with the subnet name. I have added above sg block

Comment: How about `toset(flatten([for k, v in var.subnets: {"inbound_rules"=lookup(v,"inbound_rules",[])}], [for k, v in var.subnets: {"outbound_rules"=lookup(v,"outbound_rules",[])}]))`? Of course, then you wouldn't need the list syntax, so you can drop the `[*]` referernces.

Comment: if i use flatten it still doesn't run in for_each loop giving error  "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing  │ type map of list of tuple.
╵